# Una URL para todo el sitio

Tags: javascript, asp.net, url

es posible hacer que para todo un sitio la `URL` sea la misma?

Por ejemplo `www.midominio.com` , al dar click en una sección te manda a un `iframe` y la URL cambia a: `www.midominio.com/Aplicaciones_Usuarios`. Pero se podría dejar la misma URL? que siga siendo `www.midominio.com` pero ya esté en el `iframe`? Si sí hay un método, me podrían decir como se llama o qué hay que hacer o qué lenguaje.

Comment: No comprendo bien tu pregunta. Uno de los principios de la Web es que cada cosa tiene una dirección única (es la idea detrás del URI). Podrìas tener un único _script_ que haga todo en el sitio, pero aún así, tendrías que indicar mediante algún parámetro que es lo que quieres obtener, por ejemplo `www.midominio.com/?seccion=bienvenida` ¿Qué es lo que quieres conseguir?. Esto también se podría lograr con cookies, o haciendo _post_, pero no sería lo más _natural_, ni indexable.

Comment: Exactamente pensé lo mismo, que para eso sirve el URL, pero aquí donde hago servicio social universitario me pusieron esa tarea. Que un proyecto que tienen ellos aquí haga que el URL se quede estático, no cambie mientras navego por la página. Se puede hacer eso de alguna manera? o se podría?

Comment: Si lo que quieres es no ver un cambio de dirección en el navegador, se podría. Si ves el funcionamiento de algunos sitios populares, como facebook, es más o menos así. Hay formas de lograrlo, puedes cargar en la url general un contenedor genérico y luego ir cargando y cambiando el contenido vía ajax. De esta manera, el contenido vendría de distintas URL´s, pero el _navegante_ vería siempre la misma. Me temo, sin embargo, que ese tema, sin embargo, es demasiado amplio para una pregunta de StackOverflow.

Comment: :O muchas gracias, me podrías dar una idea de cuales son los temas que tengo que investigar? para poder lograrlo?

Comment: Diría que comiences por ajax en general, por ejemplo esto: https://geekytheory.com/ajax-obtener-datos-asincronamente

Comment: Generalmente, al hacer una SPA, se hace lo contrario: jugar con el API del historial para modificar la URL sin realmente cambiar de página. De ese modo puedes guardar en favoritos una URL determinada y al cargar tu aplicación, esta detecta la URL muestra los datos requeridos.

Answer (score 2):

A ver, yo alguna vez he hecho una onepage, pero como te comentan los compañeros, no es lo normal, y lo más importante, al tener solamente una URL, te será más complicado el tema del SEO. Pero aunque no sea natural, no es imposible. Lo que yo hacía era jugar mucho con los POST, ya que es una variable que se va sobreescrbiendo, siempre y cuando utilices la misma posición. También te digo que no me acuerdo de mucho de cómo lo hacia pues hace ya unos añitos, de todos modos intentaré comentartelo lo más exacto posible. Otro contra de este tipo de páginas es lo complicado que se vuelve su mantenimiento...

En el archivo PHP, que es donde yo mostraba también el contenido HTML hacía lo siguiente:

```
$page= $_POST['page'];
switch($page)  {
case 'index':
    /* Aquí introducirías el código de la página index. Yo te aconsejaría insertando otro archivo que contenga el contenido de la página index. */
    break;
default:
    /* Lo que quieras ejecutar cuando una página no se encuentra, normalmente es un 404 not found. */
```

Luego lo que podrías hacer es que los enlaces o los botones, tengan la ID de la página a la que quieres redirigir, por ej:

```
/* Si quieres que sea un botón: (Yo te aconsejaría este) */
<button class='link' id='index'>Index</button>

/* Si quieres que sea un enlace: */
<a href='#' class='link' id='index'>Index</a>
```

Y luego con ajax lo que deberías hacer es coger la ID del elemento seleccionado y lo mandas por $_POST['page'] (o la posición que quieras) al archivo que contiene el switch.

```
$('.link').click(function () {
    $.ajax({
    'url': 'index.php',
    'data': array(
        'page' => $(this).val(),
    )
    'type': 'POST',
})
```

De todos modos, te vuelvo a repetir que yo no lo haría por muy estético que quede, pues es bastante complejo, te perjudica en el SEO y demás.

**NOTA:** El código posteado no lo he probado, y no estoy del todo seguro que el ajax funcione si lo copias, es más bien orientativo.

Espero que te ayude, un saludo.